# Call functions within event handler in Python Turtle

Tags: onclick, event-handling, python-turtle

I am trying to call the startagain function within the onclick event handler. The function does execute the input statement but does not allow the user to enter a response, the program just terminates.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
#Event Handler
def clicked(x,y):
    print(x,y)
    startagain()
#Start over
def startagain():
    again = input("Want to start over? ")
    if again == "y":
        print("okay")
#The event
wn.listen()
wn.onclick(clicked)
wn.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure if I need to somehow stop the screen from listening or if there is another approach to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me as-is.  However, I would make two changes.  First, I would have `clicked()` call `startagain()` indirectly via `ontimer()` (with no time delay), so that we don't end up with multiple `clicked()` calls on our stack.  I would also obtain input via `textinput()` rather than switch back to the console for input:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Event Handler
def clicked(x, y):
    screen.ontimer(startagain)

# Start over
def startagain():
    again = screen.textinput("Game Over", "Want to start over? ")

    if again and again.lower().startswith("y"):
        print("okay")

# The event
screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(clicked)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I thought I added another comment to this post, but I guess it was wrong. We are using Replit.com and that is my issue. The code works on other IDE's, just not that one. However, I love the additions you've made to the program. I've learned something as a result. Thank you!